# How to add space in a pdf kit table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I have a function

```
generateTableRow(doc, y, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) {
    doc
        .fontSize(8)
        .text(c1, 10, y, { width : 80, align: "center"})
        .text(c2, 90, y, { width : 130, align: "left", lineBreak: true})/*changed alignment to left for line 135,line 136 from center*/
        .text(c3, 220, y, { width : 120, align: "left", lineBreak: true })
        .text(c4, 330, y, { width : 45, lineBreak: true, align: "right" })/*changed alignment to right from center for line 137,line 138 */
        .text(c5, 440, y, { width : 45, lineBreak: true, align: "right" })
        .text(c6, 0, y, { lineBreak: true, align: "right" })//change of 0 to -10 45 to 60
        .moveDown();
}
```

Which I use to generate table rows by looping through elements of an array. Now the issue is if a particular row becomes too large its overriding on the text of the row below...

The solution I had tried is this :

```js
if(String(bill.description).length>20||String(bill.reference).length>20){
    let spaceCalc=(Math.ceil(Math.max(String(bill.description).length, String(bill.reference).length)))/20;
    console.log('$$'+spaceCalc);
    for(let i=1; i<=spaceCalc; i++) {
        doc.text('\n').moveDown();
    }
}
```

But the issue is that its adding new lines but too many new lines causing it to give a gap of one page.

PS. MY code inside the loop is something like this:

```
for(...){
    generateTablerow(...element_attributes)
}
```

Please help I want to remove override issue of text in my pdf. Also thanks in advance